# iPhone Word Game like Scrabble / Wordfued / Rummi

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am in process of creating a multiplayer game similar to the Scrabble /  Wordfued / Rummi. I am trying to see what would be best way go about implementing the UI and their interactions.

I would be having a framework which would keep track of all the pieces on the board and the AI for knowing if it is a valid move.

I am trying to figure out what could be best solution to handle the UI part. The game board would be larger than would the current iPhone screen could support. So the board would have an effect of a scroll view. The same goes for the game tiles using which user can play. These are not fixed amount of tiles/cards and the same could be more in numbers which would also need another scroll view kind of effect.
There would be many more effect's were the user can move a complete set of tiles/cards from the board and place it in another location of the board. Or even a tile in between the set of tiles on the board.

So I am trying so see if I should go with two scroll view provided by iOS and handle all the detaching the tile/card from one scroll view and placing the same in GameBoard scroll view
Or
Should I go with something like cocos-2d which provides more advance game UI handling capabilities.

Please do let me know your thoughts and feedback on what could be the best choice for the same. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Words With Friends uses native UIKit views. It is quite simple and uses a transition to move between the two degrees of magnification (close up and not close up).

You can do everything quickly in UIKit with a UIScrollview. You can use drag events to move tiles around the screen, even changing their perspective/look during dragging. Using UIAnimation would allow you to do simple frame based animation for things like dropping a tile.

Cocos2d will be quicker if you already know a similar gaming library. However if you choose it you you'll miss out on using Interface Builder and a lot of conveniences in UIKit.

If you're starting from a base of zero with either approach, then only use Cocos2d if you want particle effects (like stars and sparkles, UIKit has nothing for this).

Otherwise I'd say try UIKit, it's easier and there are more resources on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Words with Friend didn't have the kind of UI Interactions that I would be looking at. I would need two scroll views one for the tiles in hand for user to play and another with game board. The tile would be dragged by the user from one scroll view to another and dropped. I am currently evaluating between the both.

Comment: Is there no way of doing stars/sparkles and other animations with UIKit or another library? I'm doing something similar and using cocos2d just for a few effects seems a bit like overkill